# How to minimise deadlock on database table when executing operations from JAVA?

Tags: java, sql-server, web-applications, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am facing exception as 
**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Transaction (Process ID 493) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.**

When high number of users hit my site's particular transaction. This is because there is lock on a table and others requesting to acquire lock on this particular table.
Also 20 tables are used for this particular transaction and for at least five tables first delete query is executing then fresh data is inserted, which might be holding table for long and causing deadlock. Below is sample code.

```
public void save2(){
        con = DBConnFactory.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        String deleteQuery1 = "delete from TEST_TABLE1";
        String insertQuery1 = "insert into TEST_TABLE1 values ('66','7')";

        String deleteQuery2 = "delete from TEST_TABLE2";
        String insertQuery2 = "insert into TEST_TABLE2 values ('66','7')";

        String deleteQuery3 = "delete from TEST_TABLE3";
        String insertQuery3 = "insert into TEST_TABLE3 values ('66','7')";

        String deleteQuery4 = "delete from TEST_TABLE4";
        String insertQuery4 = "insert into TEST_TABLE4 values ('66','7')";

        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(deleteQuery1);
        ps2 = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery1);
        ps1.executeUpdate();
        ps2.executeUpdate();

        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(deleteQuery2);
        ps2 = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery2);       
        ps1.executeUpdate();
        ps2.executeUpdate();

        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(deleteQuery3);
        ps2 = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery3);
        ps1.executeUpdate();
        ps2.executeUpdate();


        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(deleteQuery4);
        ps2 = con.prepareStatement(insertQuery4);
        ps1.executeUpdate();
        ps2.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("success2");
        con.commit();
```

} 
    public class DBConnection {

```
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/DBConnection");
            if ((conn == null) || conn.isClosed()) {
                conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            }

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            LOG.error("DBConnFactory - JNDI namin error in getConnection =>"+ e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error("DBConnFactory - SQL error in getConnection =>"+ e.getMessage());
        } 

        return conn;
    }
}
```

I was thinking about deleting all the tables data in stored procedure and then inserting through JAVA based on my business logic. Would it help?
Please suggest how to resolve this, do I need to change my approach?

Comment: Plase update your question with the deadlock graph. Until that it's impossible to give you any answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting all of the rows in the table, try using `TRUNCATE TABLE TEST_TABLE1` instead.  Truncate is much faster than a Delete, though there are additional restrictions on its use since it is a DDL statement.

```
String deleteQuery1 = "truncate table TEST_TABLE1;";
```

Another approach you can use is combine your Delete and Insert statement into a single batch:

```
String query1 = "delete from TEST_TABLE1; insert into TEST_TABLE1 values ('66','7');";
```

A Delete statement without a where clause takes a full table lock, which will prevent other delete or insert statements from executing.  By combining the two statements into a single batch, you'll reduce the number of connections and 
latency.

You can combine all of the delete and insert statements into a single batch.

One significant concern is your use of Delete without a where clause.  Since you are running into Deadlocks, that means you have multiple connections hitting the same objects at the same time.  For example, if connectionA is inserting into Test_Table1 while connectionB is trying to delete from the table, you run tremendous risk of a soft conflict in which the connection deletes the data in connectionA before it can be used for anything else.  You really should not use Delete without a Where clause in a transaction system like this.

If you are trying to delete the specific value you're about to insert, you should add a Where clause to limit it.  That may also change the locking level from Table to Row level, assuming you have proper indexing, and eliminate the deadlocks.

```
String query1 = "delete from TEST_TABLE1 where ID = '66'; insert into TEST_TABLE1 values ('66','7');";
```

Comment: Actually i am using where clause in my delete statement according to my business need.  I am using pstmt.addBatch(); pstmt.executeBatch(); to insert data as there are multiple record to be inserted.Also  i am using  single connection object for whole transaction , failure at some point will rollback whole transaction. Since i am using PreparedStatement which is making call pst.executeUpdate(); for delete and  pstmt.executeBatch();  for insert Should i change PreparedStatement  object to Statement statement object make the queries and execute in single batch?

Comment: It can be difficult to determine the problem when you don't provide all of it.  Update your question to be more representative of your problem.  Also, the connection object in your code may not be the same as the connection to the database.  If your connection object is part of a class, you may have a separate connection for each instance of the class.  In addition, within a connection, you can have multiple sessions.  Each session can submit multiple batches, containing multiple statements.  A batch is generally the unit of work sent to the database for handling and where deadlocks occur.

Comment: Every method in every class in my web project call this static getConnection  method when there is need to interact with DB. DBConnection  is a common class where static  getConnection  is defined and it is called from different methods from different classes. Please suggest